# WPF data grid cell loop using arrow keys

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a simple data grid and I was using the down arrow key to browse through the items inside, but when I reached the last row and continued pressing down, it stopped and couldn't navigate anymore as if it has lost its focus. how can I loop through this using the keys? Is there a property for this in markup or do I need to do it in the code behind?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, what are you expecting to happen? For me, if I continue pressing the down key when the last row in the grid is highlighted, the last row remains highlighted.

Comment: I wanted to make the first row to be highlighted row after the last row is highlighted and I keep on pressing the down arrow key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to change the default selection behaviour from the markup, so you would need to do this in the code behind.

Default behaviour described here:

[Default Keyboard and Mouse Behavior in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407129%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This should be a simple thing whereby you can just do something like this in the PreviewKeyDown event handler for the DataGrid:

```
if (e.Key == Key.Down && MyDataGrid.SelectedIndex == (MyDataGrid.Items.Count - 1))
{
    MyDataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;                
    MyDataGrid.ScrollIntoView(MyDataGrid.SelectedItem);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

However, although this will select the top row as you want, the keyboard focus of the selected cell will interfere with future key presses.

If you do really want this behaviour, there is a very good article here:

[WPF: Programmatically Selecting and Focusing a Row or Cell in a DataGrid](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21202.wpf-programmatically-selecting-and-focusing-a-row-or-cell-in-a-datagrid.aspx)